# Error in Udf of pig

Tags: java, apache-pig

I am new to pig. I wrote a UDF in pig and used it in my pig script. But it gives following error

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve UserDefined.PartsOfSpeech using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
```

Here is my UDF code

```
    public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
       //my code here
    }
```

Here is my pig script

```
REGISTER /home/bigdata/NetBeansProjects/UserDefined/dist/UserDefined.jar         
 a = load '/user/bigdata/json' using TextLoader() as (input:chararray);            
 b = foreach a GENERATE UserDefined.PartsOfSpeech(input);
```

In the above code UserDefined is my package name and PartsOfSpeech is my class name

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that Pig cannot find `UserDefined.PartsOfSpeech`.

What `package` declaration does PartsOfSpeech.java have at the top of the file?

If the package declaration is `package com.my.company;` try this instead:

```
REGISTER /home/bigdata/NetBeansProjects/UserDefined/dist/UserDefined.jar         
a = load '/user/bigdata/json' using TextLoader() as (input:chararray);            
b = foreach a GENERATE com.my.company.PartsOfSpeech(input);
```

That is, replace `UserDefined.PartsOfSpeech(input)` with `com.my.company.PartsOfSpeech(input)` since the UDF is located in the package `com.my.company`.

Also, consider using the [`DEFINE`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html#define-udfs) keyword in your Pig script so you don't need to repeat `com.my.company` every time you use `PartsOfSpeech`.

```
DEFINE PartsOfSpeech UserDefined.dist.PartsOfSpeech();
REGISTER /home/bigdata/NetBeansProjects/UserDefined/dist/UserDefined.jar         
a = load '/user/bigdata/json' using TextLoader() as (input:chararray);            
b = foreach a GENERATE PartsOfSpeech(input);
```

There is more information about `DEFINE` in Chapter 5 of Alan Gates' *Programming Pig*: http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch05.html#udf_define.

Here is an example of `DEFINE` from Gates' book:

```
--define.pig
register 'your_path_to_piggybank/piggybank.jar';
define reverse org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.string.Reverse();
divs      = load 'NYSE_dividends' as (exchange:chararray, symbol:chararray,
            date:chararray, dividends:float);
backwards = foreach divs generate reverse(symbol);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before compiling your UDF(java class) make sure you have mentioned package name properly. for example if you have mentioned package name-

package com.pig.udf;

It means you need to take care of directory in your linux box as well.

you can follow below mentioned steps to create jar -

Create directory using

```
mkdir -p com/pig/udf
```

Create your java class with package com.pig.udf

Compile your java source code using command

```
javac -cp /usr/lib/pig-0.12.0.2.0.6.0-76.jar YourClass.java
```

Then go to the directory where you want to create jar for now -

```
cd ../../..
```

Now create jar using below command

```
jar -cvf yourJarName.jar com/
```

Register the jar in your script using keyword "register" followed by path of the jar
Now use your jar with keyword com.pig.udf.YourJavaClassName
for your scenerio -

```
REGISTER /home/bigdata/NetBeansProjects/UserDefined/dist/UserDefined.jar         
a = load '/user/bigdata/json' using TextLoader() as (input:chararray);            
b = foreach a GENERATE com.pig.udf.PartsOfSpeech(input);
```